# TypeError: undefined is not a function..... But the error is in Node Modules (React Native / Navigation / Expo issue)

Tags: react-native, compiler-errors, dependencies, node-modules, react-native-navigation

I'm reaching out for help on a React Native app. It hasn't been touched in years, and now I can't even open it up without getting errors.

I think the errors stem from new and old dependencies conflicting because the errors are in the node modules, which I never touched outside of typing npm i.

I've tried updating everything, but that causes even more errors and would require a lot of code to be rewritten. I'm hoping someone who has seen this before or an experienced developer can tell me what is conflicting. I'd be happy to share more code if it'd help!

PS: I'm somewhat confident it has something to do with react navigation.

Thanks for the help!

PACKAGE.JSON

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "flow": "flow"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^17.3.2",
    "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^4.1.0",
    "expo": "^48.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.71.7",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-email-link": "^1.13.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-hyperlink": "0.0.19",
    "react-native-ionicons": "^4.6.4",
    "react-native-map-link": "^2.7.0",
    "react-native-material-bottom-navigation-performance": "^0.7.8",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.5.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.20.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-viewport-units": "0.0.5",
    "react-native-web": "^0.19.4",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.0",
    "sharp": "^0.32.1",
    "tcomb-form-native": "^0.6.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.21.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.21.5",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.21.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "@bam.tech/react-native-make": "^1.0.3",
    "babel-preset-expo": "9.0.2",
    "flow-bin": "^0.205.1",
    "react-native-clean-project": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

ERRORS

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function

This error is located at:
    in withOrientation (at StackView.tsx:103)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (at Transitioner.tsx:267)
    in Transitioner (at StackView.tsx:40)
    in StackView (at createNavigator.js:61)
    in Navigator (created by KeyboardAwareNavigator)
    in KeyboardAwareNavigator (at SceneView.js:9)
    in SceneView (at SwitchView.js:12)
    in SwitchView (at createNavigator.js:61)
    in Navigator (created by NavigationContainer)
    in NavigationContainer (created by withDevTools(NavigationContainer))
    in withDevTools(NavigationContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:102:17 in reportException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:148:19 in handleException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ReactFiberErrorDialog.js:52:19 in showErrorDialog
at node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:354:30 in Component.prototype.setState
at node_modules/@react-navigation/native/src/createAppContainer.js:393:21 in NavigationContainer#dispatch
at node_modules/@react-navigation/core/lib/module/getChildNavigation.js:1:1528 in actionHelpers.actionName
at Login.js:139:38 in fetch.then.then$argument_0
- ... 8 more stack frames from framework internals

TypeError: undefined is not a function

This error is located at:
    in NavigationContainer (created by withDevTools(NavigationContainer))
    in withDevTools(NavigationContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:102:17 in reportException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:148:19 in handleException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ReactFiberErrorDialog.js:52:19 in showErrorDialog
at node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:354:30 in Component.prototype.setState
at node_modules/@react-navigation/native/src/createAppContainer.js:393:21 in NavigationContainer#dispatch
at node_modules/@react-navigation/core/lib/module/getChildNavigation.js:1:1528 in actionHelpers.actionName
at Login.js:139:38 in fetch.then.then$argument_0
- ... 8 more stack frames from framework internals
```

example of where the error shows up:

```
    componentWillUnmount() {
      this._isMounted = false;
      Linking.removeEventListener('url', this._handleOpenURL);
                                 ^
      this.subs && this.subs.remove();

      if (this._isStateful()) {
        _statefulContainerCount--;
      }
    }
```

I tried updating all my dependencies, but it got me into more trouble and didn't fix the initial errors.  I assume there are conflicts between new/old packages

Right now, I'm more concerned with getting the app started than updating everything to the newest versions.